# I am trying to make a loop that list square numbers. What is wrong with my Java code?

Tags: java, math

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (double i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            double x=1;
            System.out.print(Math.pow(x * 2));
            x++;
        }

    }
}
```

I'm getting errors that say this:

```
/MyClass.java:7: error: method pow in class Math cannot be applied to given types;
            System.out.print(Math.pow(x * 2));
                                 ^
  required: double,double
  found: double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

and I'm not sure why. I am somewhat new to coding so I'm not quite sure what to do here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `pow` expects two arguments. You mean `Math.pow(x, 2)` there.

Comment: `.pow(x , 2)` not `.pow(x * 2)`

Comment: `double x=1;` will _always_ recreate `x` with a value of 1 so the loop doesn't have any effect other than printing the same output 10 times - provided that call to `pow()` gets fixed. I think you want `Math.pow(i, 2)` here.

Comment: Wrong in every way.  Just print i*i and you're done.  No need for the variable x or Math.pow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Math.pow(x,2)` rather than `Math.pow(x*2)`. The latter is incorrect usage of the `pow` function. Alternatively, you could just print `x*x`

you would also want to do a `System.out.println` rather than a `System.out.print`, as the latter would print all the numbers one after another and you would not be able to differentiate between them.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not compiling because you are calling the method wrongly...

see the doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)

power is defined as

```
public static double pow(double a, double b)
```

so you miss 1 argument...

read carefully what a and b mean in the parameters